# Update miplevel of a texture after its creation in D3D11

Tags: textures, direct3d, texture2d, mipmaps, direct3d11

In Direct 3D 11 one can create an empty texture using [ID3D11DeviceContext::CreateTexture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and update the texel data using [ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, specifying the required mip level to change in the D3D11_BOX structure. While this is possible, is it possible to change the number of mip levels of a 2D texture after it's creation in Direct 3D?

I know this question begs a "Why would you do that?!" response, but due to some porting/testing requirements, I'm constrained to do so.

Comment: Optionally, one can set 0 to MipLevels params in D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC during creation so that based on the width and height D3D will set the mip levels to maximum (also pass nullptr for SUB_RESOURCE_DATA ptr), then later populate the mipmap levels via UpdateSubresource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change the number of mipmaps after the texture is created. You could only create another texture and using [ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to copy the required mipmaps (though It would be better to work directly on the texture with the correct mipmap levels...).